# R -- Console output redirect does not (reliably) work from function call

Tags: r, buffer, output, sink

I wrote the following code to redirect console output to text file.  All three commands' (dim, str, summary) output appears in the text file when I interactively run the code.  However, when I place the code in a function and interactively run through a function call, only the str command outuput appears.  This may be a buffering problem.  Any suggestions?

Operating System : OS X 10.9.5 (Mavericks); R 3.1.1 GUI 1.65 Mavericks build (6784)

---

This code works...

```
con <- file("FileInfoLog.txt")
sink(con, append=TRUE)
sink(con, append=TRUE, type="message")

writeLines("\n\n\n===============================================================\n")
writeLines("Dimensions are ")
dim(db)
writeLines("\n\n\n===============================================================\n")
writeLines("Structure is ")
str(db)
writeLines("\n\n\n===============================================================\n")
writeLines("Summary is ")
summary(db)

# Restore output to console
sink(type="message")
sink()
```

---

This code does not reliably work...only the str() output appears in the text file.

```
getFileInfo <- function(db) {

    con <- file("FileInfoLog.txt")
    sink(con, append=TRUE)
    sink(con, append=TRUE, type="message")

    writeLines("\n\n\n===============================================================\n")
    writeLines("Dimensions are ")
    dim(db)
    writeLines("\n\n\n===============================================================\n")
    writeLines("Structure is ")
    str(db)
    writeLines("\n\n\n===============================================================\n")
    writeLines("Summary is ")
    summary(db)

    # Restore output to console
    sink(type="message")
    sink() 

}
```

---

FileInfoLog.txt from code that works...

===============================================================

Dimensions are 
[1] 28947    17

===============================================================

Structure is 
'data.frame':   28947 obs. of  17 variables:
 $ store   : int  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ brand   : Factor w/ 3 levels "dominicks","minute.maid",..: 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ week    : int  40 46 47 48 50 51 52 53 54 57 ...
 $ logmove : num  9.02 8.72 8.25 8.99 9.09 ...
[...]

===============================================================

Summary is 
     store                brand           week          logmove            feat            price           AGE60
 Min.   :  2.00   dominicks  :9649   Min.   : 40.0   Min.   : 4.159   Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :0.520   Min.   :0.05805
 1st Qu.: 53.00   minute.maid:9649   1st Qu.: 70.0   1st Qu.: 8.490   1st Qu.:0.0000   1st Qu.:1.790   1st Qu.:0.12210
 Median : 86.00   tropicana  :9649   Median :101.0   Median : 9.034   Median :0.0000   Median :2.170   Median :0.17065
 Mean   : 80.88                      Mean   :100.5   Mean   : 9.168   Mean   :0.2373   Mean   :2.282   Mean   :0.17313
 3rd Qu.:111.00                      3rd Qu.:130.0   3rd Qu.: 9.765   3rd Qu.:0.0000   3rd Qu.:2.730   3rd Qu.:0.21395
 Max.   :137.00                      Max.   :160.0   Max.   :13.482   Max.   :1.0000   Max.   :3.870   Max.   :0.30740
[...]

---

FileInfoLog.txt from code that does not reliably work...

===============================================================

Dimensions are

===============================================================

Structure is 
'data.frame':   28947 obs. of  17 variables:
 $ store   : int  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ brand   : Factor w/ 3 levels "dominicks","minute.maid",..: 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ week    : int  40 46 47 48 50 51 52 53 54 57 ...
 $ logmove : num  9.02 8.72 8.25 8.99 9.09 ...
[...]

===============================================================

Summary is

Comment: post only relevant code ?

Comment: I thought the console output was relevant for the question, so I included it.  I significantly shortened it though.  Thanks for your remark.

Comment: :- +1 for your efforts

Answer (score 0):

When you run interactively, the `print()` command is called implicitly on each result. When in interactive mode, this is not the case. You must call `print()` explicitly. So you would need `print(dim(db))`.

The `str()` function is different because it creates it's output via `cat()` and doesn't actually return anything.

If you are using the `source()` function to run your script, you can set `echo=TRUE` to keep the auto-printing behavior.

Also, rather than bothering with setting up `sink()` and `capture.out()` commands yourself. You might consider looking at [knitr](http://yihui.name/knitr/) to make it nice looking reports with R code.

Comment: that works...thank you.  Also, thanks for the suggestion about knitr.  I will look into that.